# Scheduling scripts in cywin wihout crontab

Tags: cygwin

I have to schedule scripts in cygwin but due to administrative rights i dont have crontab neither i can install it. How do i do this ask please help.

Regards,
Swaroop

Answer (score 0):

Using the native Windows Task Scheduler feature is usually best... http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/Schedule-a-task

EDIT: Removed note about `at`. Forgot that it needs cron to be configured.